# Turning messages off does not work with an assigned symbol

Tags: warning-messages

Why does the following code not turn off the message `Sin::argx`?

```
foo = Sin;
Off[foo::argx];
Sin[4,5]
```

If I try `Evaluate`, it gives an error message:

```
Off[Evaluate[foo]::argx]
```

> Message::name: Message name MessageName[Evaluate[foo],argx] is not of the form symbol::name or symbol::name::language.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Why not `Off[Sin::argx];`? Do you mean you don't want to turn off the `Sin::argx`, and only want to turn off the message when `Sin` is stored in `foo`? Or you simply want to turn off the `Sin::argx` message without typing `Sin`?

Comment: This is part of a much larger code, and there are a number of possible functions that `foo` can be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Off`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Off.html) has an attribute [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html), and [`MessageName`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MessageName.html) has an attribute [`HoldFirst`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html). To properly evaluate your message name to `Sin::argx`, you have to `Evaluate` twice to circumvent both `Hold*`s:

```
Quit[];
foo = Sin;

Off[Evaluate[Evaluate[foo]::argx]]
Sin[4, 5]
(* Sin[4, 5] *)
```

There are other alternatives, such as using `With`:

```
With[{foo = foo}, Off[foo::argx]]
```

or defining a custom function which will evaluate your `foo` before feeding it into `MessageName`:

```
off[f_, tag_] := Off[MessageName[f, tag]]
off[foo, "argx"]
```

Note, however, that for turning the message back on, the first method with double `Evaluate` will not work because `Sin::argx` will get prematurely evaluated to `$Off[]`. Therefore, use the other two methods:

```
With[{foo = foo}, On[foo::argx]]

on[f_, tag_] := On[MessageName[f, tag]]
on[foo, "argx"]
```

Comment: TYVM, both for the explanation, as well as the workarounds.